# WAS MQ Routing message from Cluster QMGR

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using WAS MQ 7.0 and there is my scenario;

I have a Cluster Queue Manager which name `'CLUSD'` and two nodes for clustering which names `'N1' , 'N2'`. `N1` and `N2` configurations are the same.

When I tried to send messages to `CLUSD`, the qmgr tried to send messages to their nodes (`N1, N2`); on this time everything is OK. But if one of these nodes becomes down; for example if `N1` is down; I expect that `CLUSD` send all messages to `N2` and when `N1` becomes available; `CLUSD` send messages to both; but it is not working which means when `N1` is down; `CLUSD` send some of the messages (not all of the messages) to `N2` and keep other messages to his `TRANSMIT.QUEUE` and when `N1` is available; `CLUSD` send not delivered messages to `N1`.

It seems when I send messages to `CLUSD`; this qmgr set a label as a destination qmgr, I think; and keep it, while destination becomes available.

What can I do for cover this.

Comment: I solved that by change a configuration for all queues in the cluster CLUSD. I changed DEFBIND from default value 'ON OPEN' to 'NOTFIXES'. Here is the command for create queue: DEFINE QLOCAL (Q1) CLUSTER(CLUSD) DEFBIND(NOTFIXED);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you sending the messages to the queue?  When you open a cluster queue open it with BIND_NOT_FIXED option.  This will allow the receiving qmgr to decide which cluster queue to use at run time. This will also allow the receiving qmgr to route to the available cluster queues.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzah.doc%2Fqc11040_.htm

WAS should allow default binding to not fixed.
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fumj_pqdsxm.html

Comment: I'm using JMS to send message to the queue. How can I open connection with BIND_NOT_FIXED.

Comment: I saw a comment somewhere that propose to set queue DEFBIND property to BIND_NOT_FIXED. I am trying, but it's not working. You know when my CLUSSDR channel in SMSCLUSD to node N1; status is stopped, new messages that want to using this channel are storing in TRANSMIT.QUEUE. I want these messages route to another channel for N2.

Comment: WAS should support it. If not go with a cluster alias and use that cluster alias instead of qmgr in the JMS bindings definition. The cluster alias should point to a alias queue pointing to the cluster queue and set to DEFBND(NOTFIXED)

Comment: I just check DEFBND(NOTFIXED); but it's not working. As you know, by default queue has DEFBND(OPEN), I change it to NOTFIXED but it is not working. Is this necessary after these changes I must to stop and start SMSCLUSD?

Comment: CLUSTER is IBM mq (provider) specific while JMS is a standard. If you want to mix these two, use your own JNDI bindings file to bootstrap the application with queue details. Generate the JNDI bindings using JMSAdmin. Each cluster queues should have an alias defined with DEFBND(NOTFIXED). Then define a cluster alias (similar to a qmgr alias) and use that cluser alias instead of queue manager in the above JMS JNDI Q definition. When the application connects to the cluster gateway qmgr, the qmgr is forced to resolve binding with the available cluster queue.